# How to execute command, and if it fails, execute another command and return 1?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm used to this style in other languages:

```
do_something || (log_error; return 1) # do something, and if that fails, log the error and then return 1 no matter what, even if the logging fails.
```

But I can't seem to find an equivalent in bash. The problem is that the parenthesis work kind of like a function with its own scope, and the return 1 won't have the expected behavior.

This is what I have so far, but it's not perfect:

```
! do_something && log_error && return 1
```

The problem with this is that the ! is confusing, and the return 1 depends on the success of the logging.

This one is better, but more verbose:

```
do_something || (log_error; return 1) || return 1
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The `return` statement is meaningful only when inside a script or function - not on the command line. Who do you want to return 1 to?

Comment: @htor You are right, I always use this snippet inside a function. Because sometimes I need to include the script, and some other times I need to execute it as a standalone script.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper: Use `return` to return from a shell function but continue executing the script from where it was called; use `exit` to exit the entire shell (i.e. the script). Unless you're in parentheses, in which case you're in a subshell and `exit` only exits the parenthesized (subshell) expression.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, the problem is I have the payload of the script inside parenthesis (outside I only have some vars and functions I always use), to redirect the stdout/stderr (most times I want both) to a log file, and exit stopped that redirection last time I tried. That way I can have each script dealing with its own logs, instead of doing that from the caller (eg, from the cli, or a cron file).

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper: Since each script (normally) runs as a separate shell, you can redirect with e.g. `exec >output.log 2>error.log` and it won't mess up the calling script. Or you can use `{ payload; } >output.log 2>error.log` and the redirect will only apply to what's in the brackets, without needing a subshell.

Comment: @GordonDavisson You are right, with `{ ... command || exit 1 ... } > output` the output is redirected correctly, exit does not mess things up like when using parenthesis. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use braces.

```
 do_something || { log_error; return 1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exit status of the last command run is saved in the `$?` variable. So, you could do something like the following:

```
do something
if [[ $? > 0 ]]; then 
   do log_error; exit 1; 
fi
```

I like that for readability's sake. However, yours is perfectly good, you just need to replace `&&` with `;`:

```
! do_something && log_error ; return 1
```

`&&` means "execute the next command ONLY IF the previous one exited successfully" while `;` just means "execute the next command".

Comment: In your second example, `return 1` is executed in case of success.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is executed in case of both success and failure as desired. The exit status of `! ls /etc && echo "FAIL" > ~/log ; return 1` AND of `ls /etcaaa && echo "FAIL" > ~/log ; return 1` is 1.